# Can't create a connection to the remote service

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm attempting to make a call to the Yelp API in android. I am using ASyncTaskLoader but I'm still **not able to connect on the emulator.** I've never used the task loader before, so I'm sure there's some fundamental thing I'm missing, but I've been at this for several days now and I can't seem to figure it out.

I haven't implemented anything that changes the ui yet as I'm just trying to get the darn API connection working.

```
public class YelpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_yelp);

        yelpLoader load = new yelpLoader(getApplicationContext());
        load.loadInBackground();

    }

}
```

Here is my task loader.

```
class yelpLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader {

    static YelpAPI test = new YelpAPI();
   static String CONSUMER_KEY = "";
   static String CONSUMER_SECRET = "";
   static String TOKEN = "";
   static String TOKEN_SECRET = "";

    public yelpLoader(Context context) {

        super(context);

    }
    public  String loadInBackground() {
        String result = "";
        YelpAPI.YelpAPICLI yelpApiCli = new YelpAPI.YelpAPICLI();
        new JCommander(yelpApiCli);

        YelpAPI yelpApi = new YelpAPI(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, TOKEN, TOKEN_SECRET);
        test.queryAPI(yelpApi, yelpApiCli);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Error Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: tastr.tastr, PID: 4087
                  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                      at tastr.tastr.YelpActivity.onCreate(YelpActivity.java:44)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                   Caused by: org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthConnectionException: There was a problem while creating a connection to the remote service.
                      at org.scribe.model.Request.send(Request.java:70)
                      at org.scribe.model.Request.send(Request.java:76)
                      at tastr.tastr.YelpAPI.sendRequestAndGetResponse(YelpAPI.java:129)
                      at tastr.tastr.YelpAPI.searchForBusinessesByLocation(YelpAPI.java:87)
                      at tastr.tastr.YelpAPI.queryAPI(YelpAPI.java:143)
                      at tastr.tastr.YelpAPI.<init>(YelpAPI.java:189)
                      at tastr.tastr.FooLoader.<clinit>(FooLoader.java:11)
                      at tastr.tastr.YelpActivity.onCreate(YelpActivity.java:44) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                   Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                      at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
                      at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
                      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
                      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
                      at org.scribe.model.Response.<init>(Response.java:29)
                      at org.scribe.model.Request.doSend(Request.java:117)
                      at org.scribe.model.Request.send(Request.java:66)
                      at org.scribe.model.Request.send(Request.java:76) 
                      at tastr.tastr.YelpAPI.sendRequestAndGetResponse(YelpAPI.java:129) 
                      at tastr.tastr.YelpAPI.searchForBusinessesByLocation(YelpAPI.java:87) 
                      at tastr.tastr.YelpAPI.queryAPI(YelpAPI.java:143) 
                      at tastr.tastr.YelpAPI.<init>(YelpAPI.java:189) 
                      at tastr.tastr.FooLoader.<clinit>(FooLoader.java:11) 
                      at tastr.tastr.YelpActivity.onCreate(YelpActivity.java:44) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Application terminated.
```

Comment: What is the problem / question? What does / doesn't work here? You call `loadInBackground` explicitly, so that method should be firing.

Comment: The connection never happens and the app crashes. Sorry I'll edit the post to include my errors.

Comment: `Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` should be a red flag. Obviously calling the Loader from the Activity's UI thread won't work, anyways. I might suggest sticking to an AsyncTask, since from what I see in the documentation for AsyncTaskLoader looks like a lot of work just for an API call. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html... Does `YelpAPI` not perform its operations in a background thread?

Comment: Oh, nevermind. `YelpAPI` looks like a class you wrote. If you are dealing with a lot of network requests, maybe look into some libraries like Retrofit, OkHTTP, or Volley

Comment: I am using AsyncTask already I thought. What I thought this was doing was starting a new background thread to make a call to the yelp api. I tried implementing my working version of the yelp api source code, but that code doesn't work in android because of the same issue, but it works fine in eclipse.

Comment: From what I understand, Loaders are to constantly pull data from an API, which, probably is what you may want at some point, but I would recommend seeing if you can at least connect to the API with a standard AsyncTask